# Error with C++ array partition compilation

Tags: c++, partitioning

I have problem when trying to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
size_t partition(T arr[], size_t size, function<bool(T)> lambda) {
              int index = 0;
              for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                      if(fun(arr[i]) == true) {
                                     //jeśli element spełnia predykat zamien go z     arr[index] i ustaw index na 'i'
                            int tmp = arr[index];
                            arr[index] = arr[i];
                            arr[i] = tmp;
                            index = i;
                      }    
                      else { //na początku gdy index = 0, powiększ
                           if(index == 0)
                                 index = i;
                      }    
              }   
 return index;         
 }

template <typename T>
void printTable(T arr[], size_t size) {
 cout << "[ ";
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         cout << arr[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << "] ";
}

template <typename T>
bool less10(T a) {
return a < 10;
}

int main() {
int arri[] = {1,20,3,50,6,7};
size_t sizi = sizeof(arri)/sizeof(arri[0]);
printTable(arri, sizi);
size_t fi = partition(arri,sizi,
(function<bool(int)>)less10<int>);
printTable(arri,sizi);
cout << "index: " << fi << endl;
cout << endl;
double arrd[] = {1,20,3,50,6,7};
size_t sizd = sizeof(arrd)/sizeof(arrd[0]);
printTable(arrd, sizd);
function<bool(double)> lambda =  [] (double x) -> bool {return x > 10;};
size_t fd = partition(arrd,sizd,lambda);
printTable(arrd,sizd);
cout << "index: " << fd << endl;
}
```

Here you have error output:

```
6 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp `function' has not been declared 
6 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp expected `,' or `...' before '<' token 
6 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp ISO C++ forbids declaration of `parameter' with no type 
 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp In function `int main()': 
43 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp `function' undeclared (first use this function) 
  (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.) 
43 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp expected primary-expression before "bool" 
43 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp expected `)' before "bool" 
50 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp expected primary-expression before "bool" 
50 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp expected `;' before "bool" 
51 C:\Documents and Settings\Grzegorz\Pulpit\Funkcje.cpp `lambda' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Comment: And you build with a C++11 capable compiler? With a C++11 library? What compiler are you using? What version of it?

Comment: Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 that's what I know for sure

Comment: Unfortunately Dev-C++ 4 comes with a very old version of GCC, that have very bad support for C++11 (and `std::function` is new in C++11). You might want to update to 5.0 (I think it have much newer version of GCC).

Comment: I will try but I have problems with GCC

Comment: For what its worth you can do  this without `std::function<>`. And `partition()` is broken regardless, as it references `fun`, while the parameter is called `lambda`. And `int tmp = arr[index];` should be `T tmp = arr[index];`

Comment: Does not work still on DevC++ 5.6.2 How to achieve what I want without std::function<>?

Comment: Hoping your toolchain at least understands rvalue-refs, [**like this**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce964bda03393fa9). They too can be eliminated with enough overloading. And I'm not entirely convinced your partition function does what you want, but at least this should compile. Best of luck.

Comment: What's the problem with my partition function?

Comment: `index` should only be bumped on a swap. it moves as items that belong at the beginning of the partition are found. There should be no else-case (assuming I understand what you're trying to accomplish, and I *think* I do). Regardless ,can compile the suggestion without `std::function<>` ? I'm hoping you can.